# difference between Variable A and B is bigger than 2

Tags: java, integer

```
        int redsize = entry.getValue().getRed();
        int bluesize = entry.getValue().getBlue();

        if(redsize > bluesize) // difference at least 2.
```

When the difference between redsize and bluesize is bigger than 2,

But how could I make this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
if (Math.abs(redsize-bluesize) >= 2)
```

Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, it worked for me.
Next time I will check the Documentation first.

Comment: Is there also a way to get What Variable was at least 2 higher than the other Variable?

Comment: @user1621988 In that case, use the first solution I gave, checking both ways.

Comment: @user1621988 `biggersize = redsize > bluesize ? redsize : bluesize;`

Comment: read documentation? I thought they teach subtraction in school.

Answer (score 1):

If you want at least 2 more

```
if(redsize >= bluesize + 2)
```

if you want it to be greater than 2 more

```
if(redsize > bluesize + 2)
```

> difference at least 2.

```
if(Math.abs(redsize - bluesize) >= 2)
```

> difference between redsize and bluesize is bigger than 2,

```
if(Math.abs(redsize - bluesize) > 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I needed "difference at least 2.", at that is been answered.